# Is there a symbol for "never equal to"?

Tags: notation

$$A \, \text{never equal to} \, B \implies \, \forall\, \text{valid values of } (A, B)\, , A \text{ is different in value from }B$$

As opposed to $A \neq B$.
$$A \neq B \implies \exists\, \text{ a valid } (A, B)\text{: } A \, \text{is different in value from }B$$
 
Is there a symbol to conveniently represent the former.
 
$0$ is both not equal to $1$ and never equal to one. I may be given two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. $f$ and $g$ may produce different results for some $x$ (not equal), always produce the same result (equal) or never produce the same result (never equal).

$A=f$, and $B = g$.
The set of "not equal to" is a proper superset of the set of "never equal to", and both are disjoint with the set of "equal to".

Comment: How about, $f(x) ≠ g(y)$ for every $x,y$ iff $\operatorname{im} f ∩ \operatorname{im} g = \{\}$

Comment: For numbers, $0\neq 1$ means already "never equal".

Comment: Also, not sure what the juxtaposition of $BA$ in  "$B A ≠ B$" is supposed to mean

Comment: Your notation is too loose to have meaning and allow an answer. Please add some rigor.

Comment: $\forall A \ \forall B \ (A \ne B)$ is simply wrong; obviously, $A=A$.

Comment: What kinds of objects are $A$ and $B$?  IN what sense can they sometimes be the same as opposed to never the same?

Comment: You can say that for all values of A and B **satisfying a certain property** or within a certain set, $A\neq B$. But given that the characteristics of A and B must be stated, that makes it impossible to state it within a single symbol.  I don't think it's always helpful to rush so quickly to put a question on hold.

Comment: You can make this question more clear by giving a real life example of two mathematical objects for which $A\neq B$ is **not** true, but "$A$ is never equal to $B$" is **true**.

Comment: 0 is both not equal to one and never equal to one. I may be given two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. $f$ and $g$ may produce different results for some $x$ (not equal), always produce the same result (equal) or never produce the same result (never equal).

Comment: "0 is both not equal to one and never equal to one": I know what idea you have in mind, but this is expressed in an unacceptable way.

Comment: @5xum $A=B+1:A,B\in\mathbb{Z}$ might illustrate what he means. There is some $A$ which equals some $B$ but for all A for all B satisfying the equation they never equal each other.

Comment: @YvesDaoust what would be an acceptable way of expressing it?

Comment: @TobiAlafin: you must make the dependency on some parameter explicit. Otherwise "never" is meaningless. When you compare two values for equality, they don't change their minds every now and then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we follow your definition(s), yes there is a symbol for that: $F$.

Indeed,

$$\forall A, B\in D:A\ne B$$ is false (take $A=B=C$ where $C\in D$ as a counterexample).

Assuming anyway that $D\ne\emptyset$.

The predicate

$$\exists A, B\in D:A\ne B$$ is false for empty sets and singletons, and true otherwise. Hence it can be written $\#D>1$.

---

**Update**:

Speaking of the valid values of the pairs $(A,B)$ implies that you are talking about a binary *relation*, i.e. a set of pairs. Then you are looking for a way to express that the relation is *irreflexive*. Such a predicate will involve the relation, not a particular pair $(A,B)$.

I have never seen a specific shorthand, you might write $\text{Irreflexive(R)}$ where $R$ denotes the relation.

Comment: I've edited my question to include "valid values of". There may never be such a situation where we are given $(A, A)$.

Comment: 0 is both not equal to one and never equal to one. I may be given two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. $f$ and $g$ may produce different results for some $x$ (not equal), always produce the same result (equal) or never produce the same result (never equal).

Comment: @TobiAlafin: let $R:=\{x\in\mathbb R:(f(x),g(x))\}$. You can write $\text{Irreflexive}(R)$, which expresses $\forall x\in\mathbb R:f(x)\ne g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you even mean by "never equal to"?

A $x$ is equal to $y$ (in which case it is "always" equal to $y$) or it is not equal to $y$. You'll have to specify exactly what "never" means. How is it different from "not equal"?

For example, you say

$$A \neq B \implies \exists\, A, B: A \, \text{is different in value from }B$$

which is just not true. $A\neq B$ is true if and only if $A=B$ is false. That's all. There are no quantifiers here. We have an element $A$, and an element $B$, and either they are the same element (in which case $A=B$) or they are not (in which case $A\neq B$). There is nothing in between.

Comment: Not equal means that there exists a valid ordered pair $(x, y)$ such that $x$ and $y$ have different values. Never equal means that for all valid values of $x$ and $y$, $x$ and $y$ have different values.

Comment: Your definition of "not equal" is isomorphic to my definition of not equal.

Comment: @TobiAlafin Valid ordered pair in which set? Which two things are then equal? Your definition is vague, and therefore mathematically meaningless. For example, is $0$ "not equal" to $1$, or is it "never equal" to $1$? Can you give an example of a pair $A,B$ such that $A$ is "not equal to" $B$?

Comment: 0 is both not equal to one and never equal to one. I may be given two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. $f$ and $g$ may produce different results for some $x$ (not equal), always produce the same result (equal) or never produce the same result (never equal). Is my question clearer now?

Comment: @TobiAlafin Much clearer. I didn't know before you were talking about functions. However I don't know of any notation that would describe what you want. 

NOTE: Two functions are equal if they have the same domain, codomain, and they map each element of the domain to the same element of the codomain. But I didn't know you were talking about that. Your notation is very very very sloppy, and that brought a lot of confusion.

Comment: Well, $A = f(x)$, and $B = g(x)$. I'm concerned with the variables denoting the output of the functions, which is why I spoke as I did.

Comment: @TobiAlafin And this is exactly where you are sloppy. If $A=f(x)$, then (if $f$ is a real valued function) $A$ is a **number**. It is some very particular value, and an element of $\mathbb R$. However, you are not talking about this. You are talking about the **function**, so what you really want to say is $A=f$, not $A=f(x)$. The difference in meaning between these two expressions is absolutely huge. Also, how can we know that " I'm concerned with the variables denoting the output of the functions, " if you don't tell us that from the beginning?